# Set $P$ is dense in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $p >1$ be a prime number. Prove that $$P : = \{ \sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{a_j}{p^j} \, ; \, a_i \in \{0, \ldots, p-1\}, k \in \mathbb{N}  \}$$ 
is dense in $(0,1)$.

**Attempted solution:**

Note first that $$ \sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{a_j}{p^j} = \frac{1}{p^k}\sum_{j=1}^{k} p^{k-j}a_j =  \frac{1}{p^k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} p^ja_j = \frac{t}{p^k}$$ for some $t \in \mathbb{N}$ since $$ \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} p^ja_j = t $$ for any $t \in \mathbb{N}$, as this sum is simply the base $p$ expansion of $t$.

Now, given an $x \in (0,1)$ consider $B_{\epsilon} (x)$. We need show there exists $\frac{t}{p^k}$ such that $ \frac{t}{p^k} \in B_{\epsilon} (x)$. To do so, we shall dilate the $\epsilon$ ball and shrink it back down to radius $\epsilon$ to show that all neighborhoods of $x$ intersect the set $P$. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be sufficiently large. Then, by the  Archimedean property, there exists an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m \epsilon > n$. Choose $p^k$ such that $p^k > m$. Then $p^k \epsilon > n$ so that there is clearly a natural number $t$ such that $$ t \in  B_{p^k \epsilon} (p^kx).$$ Since $0< \epsilon < 1$, $0 < x <1$, $p^k \epsilon < p^k$ so $t < p^k$,  Shrinking the ball back down, we see that $\frac{t}{p^k} \in B_{\epsilon} (x)$. Thus, $P$ is dense in $(0,1)$, as desired.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: I did not understand the reasoning behind your equality
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k} p^{k-j}a_j = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} p^{k}a_j.$$

Where did $j$ go?

Comment: @PedroM. Maybe that's bad notation. The sum is just $p^{k-1}a_1 + p^{k-2}a_2 + \cdots + a_k$. I was just rewriting the order of the sum, I flipped it.

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle\frac1{p^k}\ \in P$ for all $k$, and $P$ is closed under addition. For a given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $k$ such that $1/p^k<\varepsilon$ and for $x\in (0,1)$, consider $\displaystyle\frac1{p^k},\ \frac2{p^k},\ \dots,\ \frac{\lfloor x\cdot p^k\rfloor}{p^k},\ \frac{\lfloor x\cdot p^k\rfloor+1}{p^k}$..

Comment: I see, you meant $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} p^j a_j$.

Comment: @PedroM. Yes, my apologies. A typo.

Comment: Regarding your solution, if you want to make this dilating and shrinking process work, I think you need $t \in B_{p^k\epsilon}(p^kx)$, and not $t \in B_{p^k\epsilon}(x)$.

And are $m$ and $n$ really necessary? I think it suffices to take $k$ such that $p^k \epsilon > 1$.

Comment: @PedroM. Another typo. It should have read $B_{p^k \epsilon} (p^kx)$. I suppose I used $m$ and $n$ to make is very very clear to the course graders that there's a natural number in the interval.

Comment: I see. Still, I think it makes it look more complicated than it is (which could potentially confuse the reader): it should be clear to the grader that there is some natural number in the set $(y-1, y+1)$. Also, when you say "let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be sufficiently large", the grader may ask: "sufficiently large for what?" That being said, your proof is correct.